# different width for same column of different row

Tags: html

I have a table with several rows.

My 1st row has the full width of the table table.

The 2nd row has 4 columns with different sizes for each of them.

The 3rd row's first column's width is greater than the total width (1st coloumn's width+2nd coloumn's width +25) of the 2nd row.

Which attribute should I use for this type of design? colonspan is not working in this case

Comment: It is not really related to your topic, but do you plan to use this table as a main design schema ?

Answer (score 1):

In a table the cells have the width of the column and the height of the row.

Thus, the only way to have two cells above each-other with different widths is if you use colspan.

So you will have to juggle colspans. See: http://jsfiddle.net/CBWJf/
You can maybe set the widths using [colgroups](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/colgroup/).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to have anything immediately adjacent to the shorter rows, you can make all the rows the same width (the width of the widest table row), and adjust the size of each row using colspan on the cells, and setting the cells beyond the end of the row to have no border (thus appearing not to exist). However, if you are going to have any content there, you will have to either use a different method than this or include that content in the "invisible" cells.